# How to validate and remove unwanted attributes from JSON request payload in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, express-validator

I want to validate the request payload and remove unknown attributes.

Sample request payload:

```
{
   "firstname":"john",
   "lastname":"clinton",
   "age": 32
}
```

Mandatory attributes: firstname and lastname

Optional attributes: age

Except firstname, lastname and age, any other attributes should be removed before processing the request.

Comment: If this data comes from your database, say MongoDB, you can simply select only the fields you want and ignore the others with `collection.find().select("firstname lastname")`

Comment: Its not from database, public api

Answer (score 4):

You can just create a new object:

```js
function validate({ firstname, lastname, age }) {
  if (!firstname || !lastname) {
      throw new Error('Missing requested attributes!')
  }
  return {
    firstname,
    lastname,
    age
  }
}

const validatedObj = validate({
  "firstname": "john",
  "lastname": "clinton",
  "age": 32,
  "unwanted": "value"
});

console.log(validatedObj)
```

**EDIT:** requested attributes check added.

Comment: I took the liberty to create a snippet from your code, add an unwanted value to illustrate your point, and upvote your answer :)

Comment: so ... what happens if there is no `firstname` in the object... fail

Comment: @JaromandaX Oops, i missed that point... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and generic function, `req` and `opt` are arrays of required and optional properties

```js
const validate = (req, opt, obj) => {
    opt = opt.concat(req);
    const requestHasRequired = req.every(k => obj.hasOwnProperty(k));
    if (requestHasRequired) {
        return Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => opt.includes(k)).reduce((r, [k, v]) => Object.assign(r, {[k]: v}), {});
    }
    return false;
};

//

const required = ['firstname', 'lastname'], optional = ['age'];

console.log(validate(required, optional, {
    "firstname":"john",
    "lastname":"clinton",
    "junk": "in the trunk"
})); 
console.log(validate(required, optional, {
    "firstname":"john",
    "lastname":"clinton",
    "age": 32
})); 
console.log(validate(required, optional, {
    "firstname":"john",
    "age": 32
}));
```